# How can the keyboard be closed when opening side menu (SWRevealviewController)?

Tags: ios, swift4, swrevealviewcontroller

In my case there is SearchView in the Home Screen and there is also a side menu (which is a `SWRevealViewController`). Now I want to do that when I click to the `UISearchView` then the keyboard is opening, without closing that keyboard I open the side menu (`SWRevealViewController`). This is the process.

Now the problem is that the keyboard remains open after opening the side menu.

What should I do so that after opening the side menu the keyboard is closed automatically?

Now what I tried to do this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")    
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: keyboard did not close by openig the side menu

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, hope it helps.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, SWRevealViewControllerDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton:UIBarButtonItem!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    if revealViewController() != nil {
        menuButton.target = revealViewController()
        menuButton.action = "revealToggle:"
        self.navigationController!.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        revealViewController().delegate = self
    }
}

func revealController(revealController: SWRevealViewController!, willMoveToPosition position: FrontViewPosition) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```